# Question regarding rapidly decreasing in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, schwartz-space

I have encountered some problem when trying to prove this theorm, [image]

where the definition for rapidly decreasing is that *We say that φ is rapidly decreasing if the function φ(x)p(x) is bounded for all polynomials p(x).* Can you help me out with this proof? I have no clue where should I start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you only really care about the top order terms in polynomials asymptotically (and adding 1 doesn't matter in that sense). Adding the 1 just avoids singularities at the origin. So, split analysis into a large compact region containing the origin and the exterior of this compact set where the top order terms of the polynomial are dominant.

Comment: Got it! thanks a lot.